# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'copy' django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to pass in a view of django two different objects:

APIView and PasswordResetView:

```
class PasswordReset(APIView, PasswordResetView):
    email_template_name = 'passreset/password_reset_email.html'
    html_email_template_name = 'passreset/password_reset_email.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inicio:password_reset')
    template_name = 'passreset/password_reset.html'
    token_generator = PasswordResetToken()
```

But i get the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'copy'`

There is a way to do this without this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't `token_generator = PasswordResetToken` (so without parenthesis)?

Comment: Sorry, but what you mean? that is another function from another class.@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: He just means don't call the function. Remove the parenthesis after `PasswordResetToken` @LuisBermúdez